# Wickedpdf Heroku some images are not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wicked-pdf

Everthing works perfect on my local, but on production(Heroku) some images in the generated pdf are not showing:

```
<img alt="Bg_pdf" id="background" src="file:////app/app/assets/images/bg_pdf.jpg">
<img alt="Bg_pdf2" id="background2" src="file:////app/app/assets/images/bg_pdf2.jpg">
<img alt="Bg_pdf2" id="background3" src="file:////app/app/assets/images/bg_pdf2.jpg">
<img alt="Bg_pdf2" id="background4" src="file:////app/app/assets/images/bg_pdf2.jpg">


<img alt="Step_4" id="pic3" src="file:////app/app/assets/images/steps/raka/right/step_4.jpg" style="margin-top: 20px;">
```

The #pic3 does not appear, but all the other images above appear.

Why does pic3 not appear in the generated pdf? Is there because there is some sort of maximum amount of images allowed?

In my gem file:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', github: 'mileszs/wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
```

And I am using the helper method:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag("steps/#{session[:product]}/#{session[:sving]}/step_4.jpg", :id => 'pic3', :style => 'margin-top: 20px;') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some trouble with .jpg, jpeg images, used .PNG images instead and it works well.